# d3 console doesn't show errors but chart is not rendered

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm beginner in d3 and want to draw a simple bar chart. The console doesn't show any errors but somehow the chart does not appear.

col1 is categorical variable (countries) and col2 is numerical.

It will be a great help if you guys let me know the reason and how to work it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var w = 500;
        var h = 300; 

        var dataset, xScale, yScale 

        var svg = d3.select('body')
                    .append('svg')
                    .attr('width', w)
                    .attr('height', h);

        d3.csv('data.csv', function(d) {

            var dataset = d;

            xScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                                .domain(dataset.map(function(d) { return d['col1']; }))
                                .range([0, w])

            yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                        .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d['col2']; })])
                        .range([h - padding, 0])

            svg.selectAll('rect')
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append('rect')
                .attr('x', function(d) { return xScale(d['col1']); })
                .attr('y', function(d) { return yScale(d['col2']); })
                        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like `padding` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: You need to specify a width and height for your rectangles - otherwise they'll render with width and height of 0.

Comment: For these sorts of problems, it's valuable to learn how to use the DOM inspector to see if everything is what you expect it to be. For more info, check out these links for [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/edit-dom) and [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/UI_Tour).

Comment: Thanks all, I've modified the code and it works now.